# How to change size of BufferedReader?

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I am getting a out of memory error when calling a method user BufferedReader to retreive text. The debug tool told me i should reduce its size when i ran it a number of times on the emulators. And eventually i got OOM.

So how do i go about reducing the size of the bufferedreader with this...

```
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

               imageUrl = total.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think BufferedReader has a constructor BufferedReader(Reader in, int BufferSize)

try this

```
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 1);

        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line + "\n");

           imageUrl = total.toString();
```